# Force load raster PDF

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When loading a PDF - even without running `viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.PDF")` PDF files load with recreating into vectors.
Is there a way to force PDF loading without being vectors?

I assumed that I could use LMV_RASTER_PDF: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/globals/LMV_RASTER_PDF/
But either it does not do what I thought, or I do not know how to introduce in my code.

Thank you for any assistance or ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No longer.  The "Leaflet" feature was too expensive in our conversion services, and was replaced in favor of directly parsing pdf and rendering  vectors using the same F2D shaders, inside the browser.

There may be still a way to 'trigger conversion services" to do this, but it's undocumented, and is questionable how long it will be around.

Comment: As you might expect, this was of course not the answer I was hoping for - but thank you very much for the explanation and reasoning for it.